# InputMismatchException when entering integers multiple times

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I have seen other similar questions and didn't find any solution to my problem.

Just trying to scan 2 numbers and add them together:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number1;
int number2;
int sum;

System.out.print("First: ");
number1 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Second: ");
number2 = input.nextInt();

sum = number1 + number2;

System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

the first one is printed out nicely and the next time it just crashes with IME... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: use nextLine() and cast to int

Comment: @Nomad You can't cast a string to an int. I guess you mean "parse to int"

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry :) parse of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked many times here including myself long ago.

When using `scn.nextInt()`, it still waits from input thus affecting all the inputs later on.

There are 2 approach to solve this problem.

1. Place a `scn.nextLine()` after your `scn.nextInt()`;

   ```
   System.out.print("First: ");
   number1 = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Second: ");
   number2 = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
   ```
2. Receive as `String` and parse to integer (I prefer this method)

   ```
   System.out.print("First: ");
   number1 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
   System.out.println("Second: ");
   number2 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
   ```

If you have some experiences in `C#`, they expect you do to it with the 2nd method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `input.nextLine()` after your first `nextInt()` call. `nextInt()` will leave behind the newline character.